# Self Nested SQL join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, nested, relation

I need this result this table.
This is 3 column and I want 3 results with nested node.
Really I want each node with self and parent like result

```
ID/ Number/SelfRef
21092   100 NULL
21093   50  NULL
21094   30  21093
21095   20  21093
21096   -30 21093
21097   5   21095
21098   15  21095
21099   -5  21095
```

**I need this result**

```
21097    5     21097
21097    5     21095 
21097    5     21093
```

**This is my logic**

[image: this is my logic]

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: please remove image and put table as text

Comment: Explain the logic.

Comment: I could not make out any logic from your data

Comment: i add photo about my logic

Comment: That image doesn't explain anything. Verbally express the logic behind your requirement.

Comment: So, do you want each row with 1) it's parent, and 2) with its grandparent? Is that it?

Comment: It's difficult to make out what you want but I guess two left join may be what you need: `select t1.id, t1.number, t2.id as parent, t3.id as grandparent
from my_table t1
left join my_table t2 on t2.selfref = t1.id
left join my_table t3 on t3.selfref = t3.id
`

Comment: i need parent, grandparent , grandgrandparent and ........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
;WITH
    cte1 AS
    (   -- Recursively build the relationship tree
        SELECT      SelfRef
                ,   ID
                ,   AscendentLevel = 1
        FROM        [Kharid].[IdentityGharardadKalaTedad]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      t.SelfRef
                ,   cte1.ID
                ,   AscendentLevel = cte1.AscendentLevel + 1
        FROM        cte1
        INNER JOIN  [Kharid].[IdentityGharardadKalaTedad]    t   ON t.ID = cte1.SelfRef
    ),
    cte2 AS
    (   -- Now find the ultimate parent
        SELECT      SelfRef
                ,   ID
                ,   rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AscendentLevel DESC)
        FROM        cte1
    )

SELECT  *
FROM    cte2
Order by id
```